In react-stripe-js can I change the appearance and width of the payment options?

I am using PaymentElement from @stripe/react-stripe-js, is it possible to make the payment options something like this?

Here, I edited the HTML directly, however, I don't think it's possible to do this programmatically, since the entire Stripe form is inside an iframe. Also, I found this link https://docs.stripe.com/elements/appearance-api for changing the style of the tabs, however, the width does not appear to be customizable

Thank you for the responses, I ended up using ExpressCheckoutElement from @stripe/react-stripe-js.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Does this achieve your objective?
const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
   layout: {
      type: 'accordion',
      defaultCollapsed: false,
      radios: false,
      spacedAccordionItems: true
   }
});


Documentation

Thank you for the response, I ended up using ExpressCheckoutElement from @stripe/react-stripe-js.

There's not a way to have it appear exactly as shown in your screenshot, but the accordion layout is similar to what you're looking for. You'd just need to pass "accordion" here in the options prop of the Payment Element.

Thank you for the response, I ended up using ExpressCheckoutElement from @stripe/react-stripe-js.
